# Property Transfer from a JSON response in SoapUI

Tags: xml, json, soapui, cdata

I'm trying to retrieve a value from the REST response which is similar to the following

```
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=utf-8" contentLength="1000">
  <![CDATA[{
            "timestamp":145221445,
            "status":200,
            "request":{"mbean":"someService","attribute":"someAttribute","type":"read"},
            "value":"Required value"
           }]]>
</data>
```

How do I get the value property through property transfer?

Comment: Besides the answer from @albciff you can also try the documentation: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can not easily achieve this thought a *PropertyTransfer* step.

Instead could be easier to do the same with a *Groovy script* testStep, using the following code which at first parse your *Xml* using `XmlSlurper` gets the `CDATA` element and then parse this `CDATA` as *Json* with `JsonSlurper`. Finally you can add the desired value as a property for a *TestCase* to use it later in other testSteps:

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

def response = '''<data contentType="text/plain;charset=utf-8" contentLength="1000">
                    <![CDATA[{
                     "timestamp":145221445,
                     "status":200,
                     "request":{"mbean":"someService","attribute":"someAttribute","type":"read"},
                     "value":"Required value"
               }]]>
            </data>'''
// or use this if you have your response in some test step
// def response = context.expand('${Test Step Name#Response}')

// parse the xml and get the node by it's name <data>
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def cdataNode = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'data' }
log.info cdataNode.toString()

// parse the node which contains the CDATA as Json
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(cdataNode.toString())
// access your desired value with the dot notation 
log.info json.value

// save as a property in the testCase
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("myProperty",json.value)
```